# No xaml is found at " /com.nec.win.views.Sales.xaml"

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, windows

Sales.xaml page is under "com.nec.win.views" folder

the code is

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/com/nec/win/views/Sales.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
this.NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
```

but this produce an exception

> "No xaml is found at "/com/nec/win/views/Sales.xaml"

Comment: you should use the ms-appx to render something from local assets. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx

Comment: dose `new Uri("/com.nec.win.views/Sales.xaml", UriKind.Relative);` work?